# How to limit the result returned by SMEMBERS in Redis python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I have a Redis database which contains a collection of sets and each set contains the objects of  size around 200Kb. The cardinality of each set is different and would be increasing forever.

The problem is when I execute SMEMBERS  command, I get all the members of set in one shot which consumes all of the available memory. So here I want to limit or cap the number of members returned to save the process from going out of memory.

I am using redis package for python. Also I couldn't find any helpful information in the documentation.

Can anyone suggest the practical solution?

Here the python code I use to get data from redis:

`result = redisclient.smembers(key)`

Comment: what is the desired goal ultimately? `SMEMBERS` does not have a limit argument. you could use `SRANDMEMBER` to get `n` distinct members

Comment: yes I can use `SRANDMEMBER` but the problem is I want all the members but not in one shot. So I am looking for some sort of cursor/pagination kind of thing which can return the `n` distinct members iteratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to SSCAN the set, and either break it at your ideal *n* value, or specify the `COUNT` in the call itself.

https://redis.io/commands/sscan

sscan in redis-py:
https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#redis.Redis.sscan

or the sscan_iter iterator call:
https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#redis.Redis.sscan_iter

EDIT: After re-reading your comment about the size of the set, I would caution against a too-high `COUNT` value as it could have some performance limitations.

Comment: I dont know how can I forget to check this one but anyways this guided in a right direction. :)